# MySQL Update query in While loop, takes lot of time

Tags: mysql, while-loop, sql-update

I have a table Tab1 which consists of following 6 columns

```
product_key, 
store_key, 
date_key (dates are stored as integer values. eg: '2013-july-28' is stored as 20130728),
delivery (no of quantities delivered on a day), 
sales (no of quantities sold on a day), 
inventory (no of quantities left at the end of day)).
```

I 
need to calculate inventory for all the products in all stores for all dates and this table has 3400000 rows and 12 distinct stores and 538 distinct products and dates are between 2013-July-08 and 2014-Jan-05.

For a product-Store combination, today's inventory = previous day inventory + today's delivery - today's sales.

I calculated the inventory on the first date for all Product-Store combinations using the following query.

```
    UPDATE tab1 a JOIN (SELECT sku_key,store_key,MIN(date_key) AS dt FROM tab1 
    GROUP BY sku_key,store_key )b  
    ON a.sku_key = b.sku_key AND a.store_key = b.store_key AND a.date_key = b.dt 
    set a.inventory = a.delivery-a.sales;
```

The above query took approx 2 mins. Then to calculate the inventory for the rest of dates for each product-store combination,
I wrote the following query.

```
SELECT MIN(date_key), MAX(date_key) INTO mndt,mxdt FROM tab1;
WHILE mxdt > mndt DO
-- this is to get the integer value of next day
    SELECT date_key INTO nxtdt FROM dim_date WHERE date = (select DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM dim_date WHERE date_key = mndt);

    UPDATE tab1 a JOIN (SELECT store_key,sku_key,inventory FROM tab1 WHERE date_key=mndt )b  
        ON a.sku_key=b.sku_key AND a.store_key=b.store_key AND  a.date_key=nxtdt
    SET a.inventory=b.inventory+a.delivery-a.sales_quantity;
    SET mndt = nxtdt;

END WHILE;
```

This query is taking more than 3 hours to complete.

I have created indexes on (date_key), (sku_key and store_key), (sku_key and store_key and date_key).

Any suggestions to improve the performance of this process?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET (Correlated subqueries tend to be slow on larger data sets)

Comment: Do you want me to provide some sample data?